# Add modified files to a remote branch not yet pulled

Tags: git, git-branch

If I have some files modified in my git tree and I want to add them to a remote branch that I know it exists but have not pulled in yet.
Besides doing `git stash` and `git pull` and then using the new branch is there another way?

Comment: What is the relationship of your local branch to this remote branch?  Stash, merge and rebase are your basic options here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:There is no local branch. I am in master branch

Comment: If there is no local branch, then why did you suggest doing `git stash`?  So you have a bunch of loose local files and you don't know what to do with them?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:In case some of the file modified in master have been modified in branch as well.

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` is not needed here.

If those files are not yet added, you can:

```
git fetch
git checkout abranch
# if abranch matches the name of an origin/abranch remote tracking one, 
# that local branch will automatically track origin/abranch
git add .
git commit -m "new files for abranch"
```

From [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to:

```
$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

> In case some of the file modified in master have been modified in branch as well

```
# replay your new files on top of the remote origin/abranch:
git rebase origin/abranch
git push
```

Comment: Should it be `git checkout -b`? That creates the branch right? But the branch has been created already remotely. Shouldn't it be `git checkout branch`?

Comment: @Jim yes, I have edited the answer to fix the command and include the doc.